# How do I find the exact CLI command given to Python?

Tags: python, shell, unix, command-line-arguments

I want to find out from inside the script -- the exact command I used to fire it up. I tried the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os
print os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]), sys.argv[1:]
```

But it loses info:

```
$ 1.py -1 dfd  'gf g' "df df"
1.py ['-1', 'dfd', 'gf g', 'df df']
```

You see -- it has already lost the info as to wither I've used double quotes, single quotes or there have been no quotes at all -- in the command.

**Edit**:

Here's what I'm using. All args in my script have default values, and after args are parsed with `argparse`:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I log them or if there's a log -- overwrite them:

```
logName = "." + (os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])))[0] + ".json"
if os.path.exists(logName):
    print "!!! I've found log", logName
    Args = bk_loads_json(logName)
    for arg in Args:
        exec('args.{0} = Args["{0}"]'.format(arg))
else:
    print "!!! the log of args is saved to", logName
    bk_saves_json(args.__dict__, logName)
```

defuns mentioned:

```
def bk_saves_json(myCustomDct, flNm):
    "Takes dict, and writes it to the file."

    FlNm = open(flNm, 'w')
    tmpJsn = json.dumps(myCustomDct, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    FlNm.write(tmpJsn)
    FlNm.close()

def bk_loads_json(flNm):
    "Takes file of the json and returns it as a dict."

    json_data=open(flNm)
    data = json.load(json_data)
    json_data.close()
    return data
```

Comment: You should remove `.` from your `$PATH`, otherwise somebody is going to plant a fake `ls` that will delete your hard drive :)

Comment: I don't think I have `.` in my $PATH. Is there a way I can check it? If I just put a script to pwd, I can't call it without `./`.

Comment: Well your, shell transcript suggests something different. Nevermind

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The information you're looking for (command params including quotes) is not available.

The *shell* (bash), not python, reads and interprets quotes--by the time python or any other spawned program sees the parameters, the quotes are removed.  (Except for quoted quotes, of course.)

#### More detail

When you type a command into the shell, you use quotes to tell the *shell* which tokens on your command line to treat as a single parameter.  Whitespace is used to break up your command line into individual params, and quotes are used to override that--to include whitespace *within* a parameter instead of to separate parameters.

The shell then forks the executable and passes to it your list of parameters.  Any unquoted quotes have already been "used up" by the shell in its parsing of your command line, so they effectively no longer exist at this stage, and your command (python) doesn't see them.

---

By the way, I have to wonder why you care about getting the quotes.  I have to say that at first glance it seems misguided.  Perhaps we can help if you tell us why you feel you need them?

#### EDIT

In respose to OP's comment below, here's a way to output the original command line--or at least one that's functionally equivalent:

```
import pipes # or shlex if python3
print sys.argv[0], ' '.join( [pipes.quote(s) for s in sys.argv[1:]] )
```

It just adds quotes around all params.

Comment: It just struck me -- that I could read `history` file from python.

Comment: @Adobe: That sounds like a very, very ugly thing to do. Why do you need this?

Comment: I have a script and I give it command line options specific to the dir. I thought -- if I'll make that script store a shell script in the current dir -- with the exact way I've called it -- then I would not have to re-figure all the command line options again and again. Perhaps another solution would be to make the script manually for each dir.

Comment: Ah, then no problem: when your python code prints output to generate that script, just add quotes around each param in sys.argv[1:].  Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh that's cool. I thought I would use `os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]) + " '" + "' ".join(sys.argv[1:]) + "'"`

Comment: @Adobe: The Unix way would be to take a configuration file via the command line and store a separate config file in each directory. You can use the [`ConfigParser`](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) module from the Python stdlib to parse the config files

Comment: @ron: Your workaround fails for commands that contain quotes. You should at least use something like the `shlex` module

Comment: @NiklasB.: Thanks, you're right.  I've corrected my snippet to call `quote`.

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest using:

```
import subprocess, sys
print subprocess.list2cmdline(sys.argv[1:])
```

The `list2cmdline` is used to transform a list of arguments into a single string usable from the shell. From the doc:

> Translate a sequence of arguments into a command line
>   string, using the same rules as the MS C runtime:
>
> 1) Arguments are delimited by white space, which is either a
>      space or a tab.
>
> 2) A string surrounded by double quotation marks is
>      interpreted as a single argument, regardless of white space
>      contained within.  A quoted string can be embedded in an
>      argument.
>
> 3) A double quotation mark preceded by a backslash is
>      interpreted as a literal double quotation mark.
>
> 4) Backslashes are interpreted literally, unless they
>      immediately precede a double quotation mark.
>
> 5) If backslashes immediately precede a double quotation mark,
>      every pair of backslashes is interpreted as a literal
>      backslash.  If the number of backslashes is odd, the last
>      backslash escapes the next double quotation mark as
>      described in rule 3.

Comment: The closest answer to the question, althouh I'm not yet sure which way I'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is pretty dead, but I had a need to do something like this yesterday. I was working in windows/git-bash on AWS Workspaces where the history function is pretty terrible when working in different windows, and I kept losing context, for a python-fire tool I had written which ended up taking 10-30 args each time it was called. I wanted to preserve the commands executed, because they worked as a kind of log to the infrastructure that I was implementing through the tool. I also wanted the end-result to be more human-readable than just quoting everything. I ended up taking a brute-force approach where I wrote a fair amount of code to construct a reasonable facsimile of arguments that work when copied and pasted in the command line.

https://gist.github.com/cognitiaclaeves/2208ef31740384e39052d156728742d6