# Detect within IPython which CMD/Terminal call was used to start IPython

Tags: python, command-line, terminal, ipython

Suppose that I start IPython with the following command in the Windows 10 CMD:

```
 "C:\MyFolder\ipython.exe" -i --matplotlib=qt5 --InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines="['import numpy as np']"
```

From within the IPython console that is initialized, is there a way for me to find exactly which command was used to initialize the IPython console (which is the above)?

If not, is there at least a way to retrieve the part `"C:\MyFolder\ipython.exe"`, that is the exact path to the currently run ipython file?

Comment: sorry, no dice. But you can get the executable with `sys.executable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information you're requesting (raw program arguments as passed - say - to a C program with `main(int argc, char *argv)`) is not available at the python interpreter level (a more complete - but partial because it doesn't address python command and switches - explanation is provided in [How do I find the exact CLI command given to Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411643/how-do-i-find-the-exact-cli-command-given-to-python))

`sys.argv` provides the arguments that you're passing to your script, including the script itself as `sys.argv[0]`, but not the python command line switches.

One thing you can get, though, is the executable which was launched: `sys.executable`

So the closest you can do is:

```
args = [sys.executable] + sys.argv
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer - and the link you pointed to - helped me solve my problem. However, `sys.executable` seems to *always* give the current environment's `python` path despite of whether the console was initialized via python, ipython or something else. Instead, one can simply use `sys.argv[0]`, which gives the python path if `python.exe` was used to initialize current console, but gives the ipython path in case `ipython.exe` was used

Comment: Also, notice that if one *really* wants to use `sys.executable` there, one should then do `args = [sys.executable] + sys.argv[1:]`.

Comment: my answer isn't focused enough on ipython I admit. Feel free to propose an edit to improve it and make it more suitable for ipython.